# Get order id from cart id module prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

controller/front/validation.php

```
<?php
class Paytr_CheckoutValidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $this->display_column_left = false;
        $this->display_column_right = false;

        $cart = $this->context->cart;
        $total = $cart->getOrderTotal;
        $currency = $this->context->currency;
        $customer = new Customer( $cart->id_customer );
        if ( !Validate::isLoadedObject($customer) )
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');


        //$this->context->cart->delete();
        //$isOrderX = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getRow(' SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders WHERE id_cart = '.$cart->id);
        //var_dump($_POST);

        //Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=history');
        //Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.(int)$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);
        echo 'index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.(int)$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key;
    }
}
```

I need to find order id from cart id. These are I tried. I couldnt get id_order. I was hopeful for Db query. But it doesnt work I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the problem cause deletes cookie after validate order. So It doesnt show id_cart. So I figure out like this.

```
 $isOrderX = Db::getInstance()->getRow(' SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders WHERE id_customer = '.$cart->id_customer.' ORDER BY id_order DESC ');
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.$isOrderX['id_cart'].'&id_module='.$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$isOrderX['id_order'].'&key='.$customer->secure_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with this code: `$id_order = Order::getOrderByCartId($id_cart);`

Comment: this is after validateorder function. So I could not get cart id too, cause it removes cart id from cookie also. So I need to get from the only database but database dont work. I ll get latest order this customer created.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the order is not registered, you can not get "id_order".

If the order is registered and you are sure that there is no better way, you can use the following code to find the latest cart that has been ordered:

```
$this->context->customer->getLastCart(true);
```

Comment: this is after validateorder function. So I could not get cart id too, cause it removes cart id from cookie also. So I need to get from the only database but database dont work. I ll get latest order this customer created.

Comment: In this case, you should explain more about your module and how it works. And how is the customer redirected to this page.

Comment: I've modified my post. you can use this instead of sql : $this->context->customer->getLastCart(true);